# How to add correlation/calculation to zabbix snmp data

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I have cisco catalyst 6500 switch, I want to get ethernet transmit/receive power in dBm. In order to get the stats in dBm I need to do these calculations. https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/how-to-retrieve-and-interpret-sensor-power-voltage-current-of-a/tac-p/3146797#M4410

How do I perform these correlation in zabbix, is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the thread you linked and what your asking for I think your looking for how to create an item that is based on the calculation(s) of what is returned by the 3 snmp oids entSensorType , entSensorScale and entSensorPrecision.

If so i think what your looking for is a calculated item. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated#usage_examples

However, you should look at the built in arista/juniper templates for network interface discovery and specifically the item prototypes there. That may actually be the method your looking for. I'm not sure which way will best for you. you can definitely do this with calculaged items though.